# VS.NET 2013 run build target on save item

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, customization

Assuming that I am using Visual Studio 2013.
I want to build specyfic target from my .csproj immediately after saving item.
For example:

1. I have file named template.html in my project
2. I am editing template.html
3. Click "Save" to persist changes for this file
4. This should trigger build with specyfic target: msbuild.exe /t:MyTarget

Any ideas how to do this?